# Mean time of hitting a boundary state in Gambler's Ruin problem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

i am currently studying Stochastic Processes without Measure Theory. I have a question on Gambler's Ruin problem.

Suppose each round of game are independent bernoulli trials $X_k$ for $k\geq 0$,
whereby the player wins $\$1$ with probability $p$ and lose $\$1$ with probability $1-p$.

$P(X_{k+1} = n+1 | X_k = n) = p$ , $P(X_{k+1} = n-1|X_k = n) = 1-p = q$

Let $0$ and $S$ be the absorption states.

Consider $T_{0,s} = \inf \{n\geq 0: X_n = 0 \text { or  } X_n = S\}$,

The following equations are part of a proof using First Step Analysis.

Why does the following equations hold?

$p\cdot E[T_{0,s}|X_1 = k+1, X_0 = k] + q\cdot E[T_{0,s}|X_1 = k-1, X_0 = k]$

$= p\cdot E[T_{0,s} +1|X_0=k+1, X_{-1} = k] +q\cdot E[T_{0,s} +1|X_0 = k-1, X_{-1} = k]$

$= p\cdot E[T_{0,s} +1|X_0 = k+1] + q\cdot E[T_{0,s} +1|X_0=k-1]$

Initially, i thought $E[T_{0,s} |X_1=k +1,  X_0 =k] = E[T_{0,s} |X_0 = k+1]$ because of the time homogeneous property, whereby the past has no effect and the number of bernoulli trials resets to $0$ at $X_0 = k+1$ since the future bernoulli trials start at $X_1 = k+1$.

But from the above equations, i am wrong. Someone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time-homogeneous property is important, but you haven't quite applied it right. On the LHS you know that $X_1 = k+1$ (and that $X_0 = k,$ but that's irrelevant for going forward). On the right-hand side you know that $X_0 = k+1.$ These are statements about different points in time.

The average time it takes to hit the barrier from the state of $k+1$ is always the same regardless of history, but $T_{0,s}$ is the total time from time zero, not from whenever you were at $k+1.$ Since when $X_1 = k+1$ one time step has already elapsed the expected total time to hit the barrier will be one time step longer than if you were at $k+1$ at time $0.$ So you have $$ E(T_{0,s}\mid X_1=k+1, X_0 = k) = 1+E(T_{0,s}\mid X_0=k+1) = E(T_{0,s}+1\mid X_0=k+1).$$